# Understanding why I can't use index on the result of the size function on a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

When trying:

```
a = [ 1 1 ; 1 1 ];
size(a)(1)
```

I get

```
Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index
expression
```

My understanding is that the result of `size(a)` is a matrix of size `1 2`.

Question: Why does `size(a)(1)` not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you can't index the result of a function like that in MATLAB without creating a temporary.

```
temp = size(a);
temp(1)
```

will work.  There are often other ways of getting what you want, however.  In your example, you can make use of the `dim` argument in the function `size(X,dim)`:

```
size(a,1)
```

That will get you the size of the first dimension directly, avoiding the need to create a temporary variable.